# how to get group price on magento backend

Tags: magento

part A:   `$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();`

part B:   `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();`

How to get **"Group Price"** ?
Is there any way ?

Comment: Hello can you please give more description about your question ? I mean do want to get the price of the group product or bundled products am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are doing well.

As far as according to your problem we are having one method in magento to get the group price, but it will use full to you only if you are having the object of the $product. You can check that using getGroupPrice(). Example of the same is given below.

```
<?php 
$login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); 
//Check if User is Logged In

if($login && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') >getCustomerGroupId()==5)
 {
      $groupPrices = $ProductObject->getData('group_price');
      $Groupprice= $groupPrices;

       if (is_null($groupPrices)) 
       {
        $attribute = $ProductObject->getResource()-          >getAttribute('group_price');
         if ($attribute)
         {
            $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($ProductObject);
            $groupPrices = $ProductObject->getData('group_price');
            }
        }
        /* check group price exit nor not */
         if (!is_null($groupPrices) || is_array($groupPrices)) {
            foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {

            if($groupPrice['cust_group'] == Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()){
            echo $Groupprice = $groupPrice['website_price'];
            echo "<br/>";   
            echo $Groupprice=$groupPrice['cust_group'];
            break;
            }
            }

         }
         /* $Groupprice  is null mean group price is not  exit*/
         if(!is_null($Groupprice)){
             //group price eixts
             ?>
             <span class="price-label"><?php echo "Special Group Price " ?></span>
            <?php 
         }else{
             //Group price is exits.
             ?>
             <span class="price-label"><?php echo "Now" ?></span> 
         <?php }
    ?>
    <?php }

    else { ?> 
    <span class="price-label"><?php echo "Now" ?></span>   
    <?php } ?>
```

Hope this example will be use to and Waiting for comments !!!!

Comment: thanks for your help. but i want run script on magento backend without customer group.